# Date is empty in view textboxfor when adding type "date"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Weird problem that is probably very obvious. In my view model I have a date, which I set in the controller. When I render the textbox in the view, it is empty.

**View model:**

```
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
   public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    //GET: InvoicePrice
    public ActionResult Index(InvoicePriceViewModel model)
    {
        model.DateStart = DateTime.Now;
        return View(model);
    }
```

HTML of view:

```
    <p>
      Date:<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateStart, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Invoice date", type = "date" })
     </p>
```

When I open this, I get the empty textbox here:

[image]

And I would expect to see "28-11-2017" as my current date.

I guess I am missing something obvious here. But what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a couple of issues here and I'll try to explain them.

The first problem is that [date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) accepts values only in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and displays them based on the browser localization settings:

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

This means you need to change your `DataFormatString` and also set `ApplyFormatInEditMode` to true:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

However it still won't have any effect because in order for your custom format to be taken into account you need to use `Html.EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateStart,
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Invoice date" } })
```

Or you can ignore `DisplayFormatAttribute` and specify the format in the `Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateStart, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Invoice date", type = "date" })
```

Comment: Hey man! Makes absolutely sense. However, I tried both approaches and neither works. I understand why it didn't work before, but now after changing the format I can't really understand why it still shows nothing. Anything obvious we could've missed?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard, this should be working fine, I've tried it. You can inspect the source code of the page and check in which format the value is rendered `value="2017-11-28"` or just remove the `type = "date"`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>
      Date:<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem  => item.DateStart, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Invoice date", type = "date" })
    </p>
}
```